# How to load a specific directory in a Azure container into powerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi

I want to load data into powerBI from a specific directory from an Azure container in an Azure storage account , I have tried using get data -> Azure -> Azure Blob Storage but it's getting all the data in that container , But I need only data from a specific directory in that container

Any help Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know this is like 3 years late, but this works if you point directly to the file.

`https://yourdls.blob.core.windows.net/folder/file.parquet`

PowerBI will then prompt you for a PW or a key. You want to use a key of course.

Comment: This worked for me, but with Get Data > Web instead of Azure Blob

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this capability is not supported in Power BI as of today. Here are some similar ideas on **Power BI Ideas** forum that you can vote for:

- [Allow PowerBI to connect to subfolder in azure blob storage](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=cde45d1a-75ec-4365-a7d8-f0fc1bb6c3ac)
- [Allow power bi to connect to a particular blob file from a subfolder in the Azure Blob Store](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=5ea6dba0-b1e4-45d4-863a-de49a86dae87)